# How to have bash write two bash history files without changing bash source code?

Tags: bash, bashrc

I want to have bash_history content duplicated in another file. Why? Because a malicious user can edit his own bash_history file. I know that that is not what bash_history is there for. So, is there a way for bash to write two bash_history files? One the normal one and another a copy in a configurable directory?

**EDIT**

Has anyone edited the bashhistory.c file of the bash source code to give me some pointers as to what changes need to be made to this file to get another file to write the history to?

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic.

Comment: what do you mean by malicious user? if he has a plain user account he should not be able to do harm unless he has sudo rights (or worse, root access) than that should be e.g. logged with sudo su disabled. audit is not meant to be implemented as your idea/proposal.

Comment: @Zina The mode of bash_history is readable and writeable by the user as bash itself is not setUId to root (of course) so user can change his history usage. How is it possible to get real bash_history is the issue. One way would be to just have another history file written which requires code changes.

Comment: @Sam - yes I know what you are saying, I just commented that this is not the way to do it. To destroy something he has to have sudo rights or know the root password (bad practice to give away this). So if you disable `sudo su` he can destroy it only with `sudo <any destroy command>` which can be set up to be logged and you will now who sudo-ed and did it. Even if you do the double bash_history you want to, what about `sudo zsh` (sh, csh, tcsh,..) which do not save the history to bash_history?

Comment: @Zina In view of your comments, perhaps I should have asked my question differently: How to get history of commands executed by a user? In any case, To address your last point, and a good one, I would remove/disable csh, tcsh, sh, etc. I am not concerned about his destroying something but to check what he has been doing that is not in the scope of his/her work but nonetheless has permission to the resource. E.g. tar-ing an entire folder.

Comment: Check out these answers [Log all commands run by admins on production servers](http://serverfault.com/questions/470755/log-all-commands-run-by-admins-on-production-servers) and [How do I log every command executed by a user?](http://serverfault.com/questions/336217/how-do-i-log-every-command-executed-by-a-user)

Answer (score 0):

Use hard link to establish a copy in some other area.

```
cd
ln .bash_history /path/to/copy/writeable/by/user/too
```

But it's still a copy, so you'd have to periodically make your own copy from that path, and keep a history of the history.

But I has a 'malicious' user don't even have to use a history file ;-)